Segmentation fault when run binary compiled with toolchain
I have crosstool-NG c++ toolchain (gcc and Boost library built with it) and I build this hello world project using it:
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(HelloBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Boost 1.84.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(HelloBoost main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(HelloBoost ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found")
endif()

main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::filesystem::path p = boost::filesystem::current_path();
    std::cout << "Current path is: " << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

toolchain.cmake:
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/tmp/toolchain/bin/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/tmp/toolchain/bin/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu-g++")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

It's compiling with no problem but when I run binary on the target operating system I get segmentation fault:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib:/tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib ./HelloBoost

What I am doing wrong?

Pop open your debugger and find out where it crashes.

I only have gdbserver for target system and cross gdb for the build one. Looks like I supposed to start gdbserver and attach to running process on target machine and connect to it with the cross-gdb. The problem is: binary crashes instantly when I run it and I can't connect to it

Start the gdbserver and rather than attaching to a running process, use gdb to run the process.

One trick I've sometimes used when I (for some reason) couldn't start a program directly from the debugger or couldn't attach quick enough is to put a raise(SIGSTOP); at the beginning of main to cause the program to freeze, then attach the debugger to the process and continue it by sending a SIGCONT signal to it.

The problem was with the dynamic linker ("ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"). To successfully run the program I had to change it to the linker from my toolchain by running the command:
patchelf --set-interpreter /tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 HelloBoost

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib:/tmp/toolchain/x86_64-pt-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib ./HelloBoost

